# What does A. E. C. denote in the poem about Edward Anti-Teller?

Tags: poetry, historical-context, harold-p-furth

["Perils of Modern Living"](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~hsg/134/poems/harold-furth-perils-of-modern-living.txt) is a poem written by the physicist Harold P. Furth inspired by a speech on antimatter by Edward Teller. (Hat-tip to our comrades at [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/159913/2235) for making me aware of this poem, although I'm pretty sure I'd heard of it, or at least the [macassar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimacassar) part, before.)

> Well up above the tropostrata
>      There is a region stark and stellar
>      Where, on a streak of anti-matter
>      Lived Dr. Edward Anti-Teller.
>
> Remote from Fusion's origin,
>      He lived unguessed and unawares
>      With all his antikith and kin,
>      And kept macassars on his chairs.
>
> One morning, idling by the sea,
>      He spied a tin of monstrous girth
>      That bore three letters: A. E. C.
>      Out stepped a visitor from Earth.
>
> Then, shouting gladly o'er the sands,
>      Met two who in their alien ways
>      Were like as lentils. Their right hands
>      Clasped, and the rest was gamma rays.

**What does A. E. C. represent?** I'm guessing it's not just a made-up sci-fi acronym like Antimatter Energy Company, but probably refers to something real, perhaps associated with space exploration (as it was conceived of back in the 50s) or with Teller specifically.

Comment: Atomic Energy Commission, perhaps?

Comment: Mick is right.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheimer_security_hearing for a description of the political events that motivated Furth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stands for [Atomic Energy Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Atomic_Energy_Commission), commonly known as A.E.C. In the real world, [Edward Teller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Teller) was an early member of the Manhattan Project, sometimes called "the father of the hydrogen bomb", and he was involved with the Atomic Energy Commission including [proposing projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Chariot) and [testifying against Oppenheimer in their security clearance investigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheimer_security_hearing). I looked into the history of this poem in high school over 2 decades ago and have only what facts have stuck in my brain over that time.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for answering my question! I've added a few links to help improve this answer's sourcing, as it's always better to have a supported and verifiable answer than a brief one-liner without backup.